# Using WRS ancova function with missing values in r

Tags: r, missing-data, anova

I am trying to run a robust ANCOVA with the WRS package (not WRS2) in r using the `ancova()` function ([source code](http://www.statpower.net/Content/311/R%20Stuff/Rallfun-v20.txt)), although my data has several missing values after cleaning.
If I run the code:

```
dvGr1 <- c(1.8, NA, 2.4, 2.1, NA, 1.9, 3.0)
cvGr1 <- c(66.2, 49.4, 75.8, 60.8, 59.4, 58.3, NA)
dvGr2 <- c(NA, NA, 1.6, 2.2, 1.5, 1.8, 1.9)
cvGr2 <- c(NA, 74.3, 67.5, NA, 65.9, 57.3, 58.5)

ancova(cvGr1, dvGr1, cvGr2, dvGr2)
```

I get:

```
Error in if (nuhat < 2) stop("The degrees of freedom must be greater than or equal to 2") : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I understand this is because the code is looking for values that are not there, but if I use `na.omit()` I get the error `x1 and y1 have different lengths`.

My question is, is there are a way to run `ancova()` with missing values in the dataset?

Comment: It would be easiest for everyone if you could whip up a (non)working self-sustaining example and post it here.

Comment: Sorry Roman, please above code. Thank you